# What is this A-shaped plastic tool?

Tags: tools

Some time ago, this black plastic tool was given to me by a guy from an LBS, and I remember thinking "oh, that might come in handy".

Now, a couple of months later I've completely forgotten its purpose.  What is it for?

[image: Unknown black piece of plastic]

I know what the coin is for, but not the other thing.

Comment: Aside - if you can put a ruler in the photo rather than a coin, it gives a better idea of size.   I've never seen a euro coin and have no idea how big it is.

Comment: The diameter is exactly [19.75 mm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_euro_cent_coin). Or just over 3/4" for our US friends.

Comment: For comparison, the US small one-cent coin is only slightly smaller (19.05mm).

Comment: The 10 euro cent is good for some old style screws if you have nothing better at hand.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is a valve core removal tool for presta valves. They can be used to replace a valve core or to temporarily remove the core when filling sealant through the valve (for tubeless tire setups).

Comment: Yes of course, now I remember!

Comment: Pro tip: Put it in a zip baggie with a label before dropping it back into your tool box/drawer.

Comment: Less common use: remove or install valve extenders.

Comment: I’d add that it’s plastic which is likely to fail. There are metal versions (Schwalbe makes a nice one) which are much stronger.

Comment: @Michael it'll be fine. Its small size means you lever really have that big of a moment arm on it. The metal ones are great to have in your work area. These are great for your trailside repair kit.

Comment: For trailside (and home) use I really like the valve caps that have an integrated core removal tool. They are never misplaced.